what command of git could I use to bring me all the commit's title and his author to see it in a specific format
I am using this command

git cherry -v master release | cut -d " " -f3-

to bring me all the commits of a PR, and it is written as follows:
Hi I am the first commit (#0001)
Hi I am the second commit (#0002)
Hi I am the third commit (#0003)
Hi I am the fourth commit (#0004)

but I can't get with a command in git to put the author of each commit next to the title like this:
Hi I am the first commit (#0001) @Walt Whitman
Hi I am the second commit (#0002) @Michael
Hi I am the third commit (#0003) @Homero
Hi I am the fourth commit (#0004) @Miyomoto


git cherry is a custom reformat of some git log options for "symmetric" ranges, for your
git cherry -v master release | cut -d " " -f3-

you'd start with the --cherry option, like
git log --cherry --oneline master...release

and paw through the --pretty option's format specifiers to get exactly what you want, a first cut:
git log --cherry master...release --pretty='%m %s @%an'

